# Angular + Chart.js / Argument of type 'ChartPoint' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & ChartPoint'

Tags: angular, typescript, charts

I use `angular` and `chart.js`.

How to add element to data array. I do not understand why the guy is not good.

I want add any data in `data`

```
public readingChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
        {
            data: [],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#648ed0',
            label: 'Chambre froide'
        }];
```

type of `data` is `Array<number | null | undefined> | ChartPoint[]`

type of `element.value` is `number`

```
const p: ChartPoint = {
        x: element.value
};
this.readingChartData[0].data.push(p);
```

I have this error:

```
Argument of type 'ChartPoint' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & ChartPoint'.
  Type 'ChartPoint' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a solution:

```
(this.readingChartData[0].data as number[]).push(element.value);
```